# How to move Label within a panel using MouseMove event?

Tags: .net, delphi, mouseevent, panel, delphi-prism

I know this should be very simple especially given all the information and example codes online, but for some reason I just can't get this to work.

I have a Label and a Panel on a winform. I want the label only to follow the mouse pointer when it enters and moves within the panel.

I got it working, but its location is totally shifted and it is always changing when you move the winform.

Here is the MouseMove and other events:

```
constructor MainForm;
begin
  InitializeComponent();
  label2.Visible:=false;
end;

method MainForm.panel1_MouseMove(sender: System.Object; e: System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs);
begin
  //label2.Location := panel1.PointToScreen(e.Location);
  label2.Location := self.PointToScreen(e.Location);
  label2.Invalidate;
end;

method MainForm.panel1_MouseEnter(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
begin
  label2.Visible:=true;
end;

method MainForm.panel1_MouseLeave(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
begin
  label2.Visible:=false;
end;
```

**Update** As suggested by larstech, I modified the code, but the label is still showing up outside of the box as the image below is showing.

[image: myimage]

Thanks,

Comment: Is the Label a child control of panel1?  It's not quite clear.

Comment: @LarsTech no it is not. the label is on the winform not within the panel. Panel1 text is the label containing the text "Panel1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know `delphi-prism`, but wouldn't it just be:

```
label2.Location := e.Location;
```

Since the Label is not a child control, try this:

```
label2.Location := new Point(panel1.Left + e.Location.X, panel1.Top + e.Location.Y);
```

Obviously, I may not have the syntax right.

If you are just trying to move a ToolTip, this works in c#:

```
private ToolTip _tips = new ToolTip();

private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  _tips.Show("test", panel1, e.Location.X + 10, e.Location.Y + 10);
}
```

Comment: I made the label a child of the panel and now it is working but I have to keep the mousedown to show the label

Comment: @digitalanalog Updated answer.  I would think a timer would work potentially better since the label would cause the panel's MouseLeave event to fire once the mouse goes over the label.  You could disable the label, but then it draws disabled.

Comment: why is MouseLeave firing everytime MouseEnter fires. That is confusing.

Comment: All this effort is to have a simple ToolTip or Hint as they used to have in Delphi for Win32. Apparently, ToolTip text is only supported within ToolStripItems. By the way, your updated works the same way when I made the label a child of panel. So, your syntax is correct.

Comment: @digitalanalog Updated answer by adding c# ToolTip example.

Comment: Great Thanks for your help LarsTech. ToolTip Class is working great.